# MongoClient not found in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have downloaded `php_mongo-1.3.2RC1.zip` from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads
Then I have extracted all of them in my `C:\xampp\php\ext` directory. To use mongodb though php file located in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php' directory, I have added `extension=php_mongo-1.3.2RC1-5.2-vc9.dll` this line to `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`.

Yet I have got this error `Fatal error: Class 'MongoClient' not found`. What can I do to make it work?

I am using `Xampp` on `windows 8 64 bit` running on `php 5.2`.

I have tried writing `php` on `cmd` and it returns this following lines:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20100525
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
```

I have tried `phpinfo()` as @j0k has asked, and it returned:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File   C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

Comment: Have you edited the right php.ini ?

Comment: @j0k, Do we have multiple php.ini? :S

Comment: Yes it can happen. Which one did you modify? Also, check with a `phpinfo()` if you can see the section `mongo`.

Comment: @j0k, I have added necessary details you have asked in my question.

Comment: Is `C:\xampp\php\php.ini` the file you modify? Check the phpinfo from a webpage like: http://free.box.free.fr/info.php3 to see the mongo part. Did you restart Apache after editing your php.ini?

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
pear install -f pecl/mongo
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you use `php 5.4` (info from my web server):

```
$ php -v; phpize -v
PHP 5.4.11 (cli) (built: Feb 10 2013 03:38:26) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20100412
Zend Module Api No:      20100525
Zend Extension Api No:   220100525
```

API module versions are identical.

```
…
Module compiled with module API=20060613
…
```

It is `php 5.2` (from source code):

```
$ grep '#define ZEND_MODULE_API_NO' php-src-php-5.2.17/Zend/zend_modules.h| sed 's/#define ZEND_MODULE_API_NO//'
 20060613
```

Check you version php (`php -v; phpize -v`) and setup php-mongo-driver. You can see versions in `phpinfo();` (*recommended*; PHP API, PHP Extension, Zend Extension, Thread Safety)

Comment: Thanks, this helped! I have two versions of PHP was using PHP 5.6.13 and 5.4.45; Switched to 5.4.45, now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to restart your Apache. Apache will not try to reload the configuration upon edit. For xampp you can do this in the cornor pressing shutdown or restart, if I Remember correctly. Alternative you can restart your pc

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows) page:

**Note: Additional DLL dependencies for Windows Users:**

In order for this extension to work, there are DLL files that must be available to the Windows system PATH